# How can I change the colors of fbterm using escape sequences?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, colors, fbterm

From [fbterm(1)](https://man.cx/fbterm) we can read:

> FbTerm supports xterm's 256 color mode extension.  (...) 
>   But xterm's 256 color escape sequences conflict with the linux sequences implemented by FbTerm, so private escape sequences were introduced to support this feature:
>
> ```
>    ESC [ 1 ; n }                   set foreground color to n (0 - 255)
>    ESC [ 2 ; n }                   set background color to n (0 - 255)
>    ESC [ 3 ; n ; r ; g ; b }       set color n to (r, g, b) , n, r, g, b all in (0 - 255)
> ```

How can these escape sequences be written with the command `echo -ne`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use e.g.

```
echo -ne "\E[2;32} "
```

which should print a blue space. (32 is the 32nd colour in the default 8-bit colour table which seems to be blue.)

(Of course you can also use `\x1b` or `\033` instead of `\E` to represent the escape character.)

To view all 255 colours you can use `for i in {0..255}; do echo -ne "\E[2;$i} "; done; tput sgr0; echo` or `for i in {0..255}; do echo -ne "\E[2;$i}$i "; done; tput sgr0; echo` which also includes the number of the colour.

Example:
[image: colour output example captured with fbgrab from framebufferconsole]

Comment: Do you have a reference for the default colour palette?

Comment: No, but you could try something like `for i in {0..255}; do echo -ne "\E[2;$i} "; done; tput sgr0; echo`, this should print 255 coloured spaces and reset every text-colour-related setting to defaults in the end (`tput sgr0`).

Comment: Indeed - perhaps you could add this to your answer with a screenshot of the result? Numbers in the color would be even better :-)

Comment: Done, I added both one-liners (-:

Comment: How do you end the color without `tput sgr0` ?  What is the escape sequence?

Comment: @GringoSuave apparently it's possible to use `echo -ne "\E[0;0m"` (see e.g. https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797#8-16-colors)

Comment: Ok, that is the standard one.